# How to create a burn folder?

Tags: cocoa

my app needs to both burn discs and create burn folders. i'm able to use the `DiscRecording` framework, and am delving into its many options for the burn disc methods, and am starting to get that, but i don't see any reference to creating a 'burn folder'.

i've also looked in `NSFileManager` (thinking that it was a key that needs to be set), and also searched the docs and this site for 'burn folder', with no result.

it's probably that i am overlooking something really obvious about how to do this programmatically.

will anyone shed some light here? 
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a directory with an extension of `.fpbf`.

Comment: Good one. ( Finder Backup Burnable Archive file ) http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fileextensions/f/fpbf-file.htm